# PyTorch autocomplete in PyCharm seems missing a part

Tags: pytorch, pycharm

PyTorch autocomplete in PyCharm seems missing a part, while in VSCode, it works well.

Example:

In VSCode:
[PyTorch autocomplete in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxTbk.png)

In PyCharm:
[PyTorch autocomplete in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN8gN.png)

PyCharm version: 2022.2.4

VSCode version: 1.75.1

PyTorch version: 1.13.1

As you can see in the image, for a pytorch tensor `t`, I would get the autocompletion option `t.max` in vscode , but I would not get it in PyCharm.

I wonder if I could get PyCharm work well just like VSCode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.